IOS bluetooth connection being lost when packet size goes over 160 bytes (mtu 256)
So, I'm using the package called flutter_reactive_ble and I'm comunicating with a 3rd party device via bluetooth. I connect and communicate via bluetooth sendind and receiving packages with size ≅ 20 bytes, which works perfectly fine. When I enter the update mode, where I send packages with 240 bytes it disconnects the iPhone with a timeout error.
Note: This issue does not occur in android!
flutter_reactive_ble version: 5.3.1
I already tried to contact te 3rd party but id doesn't seem to be a good idea to change the mtu size, which would help since my other app which communicate via bluetooth uses 512 mtu size and iOS runs ok.
Already tested different iOS versions and this error occus in newer and older versions.

If you aren't doing so already, make sure that you are also sending a request to maximize the size of your data packet. The optimal size is to set the maximum packet length to 251 (which is the maximum according to the Bluetooth specification) and set the ATT_MTU to 247. If this doesn't work, then try different combinations or a smaller ATT_MTU size. I believe that the maximum ATT_MTU supported by some (maybe all) iOS devices is 185 - which means that you can send a payload of 182 per transaction. I am not sure if this is documented by Apple, but several links mention this as can be seen below. I would experiment with an MTU size of 185 or lower to see if the problem goes away.

BLE MTU Max size on iOS
Change iOS BLE MTU Size
Maximizing BLE throughput: Larger ATT_MTU
iOS MTU Size why 185
Change BLE default MTU for iOS

